# A finite abelian group $G$ has invariant factors $(m_1, m_2, ..., m_k)$. Show that $G$ has an element of order $s$ if and only if $s$ divides $m_k$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

> Suppose a finite abelian group $G$ has invariant factors $(m_1, m_2, ..., m_k)$. Show that $G$ has an element of order $s$ if and only if $s$ divides $m_k$.

Because these are the invariant factors, we then know that $G \cong \mathbb{Z}_{m_1} \times \mathbb{Z}_{m_2} ... \times \mathbb{Z}_{m_k}$.  Also, because it is in invariant factor form, $m_1$ divides $m_2$ ..., $m_{k-1}$ divides $m_k$.  I'm not sure how to proceed. I know that the order of $s$ must divide the order of $|G|=m_1*m_2*...*m_k$, but I'm not sure how to argue that it must divide $m_k$ specifically.